# Where can I see how long it took for checked-in luggage to be made available at the baggage reclaim area for past flights?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, online-resources, timetables

I'd like to estimate how long it will take me to leave the airport. If I have checked-in luggage and the immigration is smooth or absent (e.g., domestic flights), the bottleneck is typically waiting at the baggage reclaim area. Where can I see how long it took for checked-in luggage to be made available at baggage reclaim area for past flights?

FlightStats [has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLQ5b.png) the flight gate time and flight runway time  for departure and arrivals, but not the  time when checked-in luggage show up at  the baggage reclaim area.

Comment: Which airport(s)?

Comment: @Traveller Any. I'm looking for a solution which takes a flight number as input, and give me a history of baggage reclaim time.

Comment: I doubt the information is available on a global or even widespread basis. Maybe a few airports publish it? But what would be the info? First bag? Last bag? There can be a significant gap between the two. Unless it’s CDG of course, where it varies between very long and extremely long.

Comment: @jcaron thx, min, max, std, median, etc

Comment: You are asking for the impossible. Nobody has all that data in one convenient place for you to query.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks, you're welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Random data point (Gatwick, back from september 2013): https://www.gatwickairport.com/globalassets/publicationfiles/business_and_community/all_public_publications/about_gatwick/baggage-posters/september_2013_combined.pdf Some airports will also show the current status of bag delivery (first bag, last bag). Not sure if that information is available in standardized feeds, I don't even think the arrival gate or baggage claim number are widely available via third-party tools, are they?

Comment: @jcaron Thanks, very interesting PDF! I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comment section.

There is no generic solution to view how long it took for checked-in luggage to be made available at the baggage reclaim area for past flights.

Some airports publish some statistics, e.g. [statistics from Gatwick airport in September 2013](https://www.gatwickairport.com/globalassets/publicationfiles/business_and_community/all_public_publications/about_gatwick/baggage-posters/september_2013_combined.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://www.gatwickairport.com/globalassets/publicationfiles/business_and_community/all_public_publications/about_gatwick/baggage-posters/september_2013_combined.pdf)):

[image]

Some airlines have some baggage claim guarantee, e.g. https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/baggage/baggage-claim/20-minute-guarantee ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220511091917/https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/baggage/baggage-claim/20-minute-guarantee)):

> If your bags are not at baggage claim within 20 minutes of your plane’s arrival at the gate, we’ll offer you a $25 discount code for use on a future Alaska Airlines flight, or 2,500 Alaska Airlines Mileage Plan™ bonus miles.
>
> In the rare instance that we don't meet our 20 minute guarantee, just get ahold of us at the baggage office within 2 hours of your flight's arrival for your discount code or miles. You can simply speak with one of our customer service agents at the airport.

---

Comments:

> - Random data point (Gatwick, back from september 2013): [gatwickairport.com/globalassets/publicationfiles/…](https://www.gatwickairport.com/globalassets/publicationfiles/business_and_community/all_public_publications/about_gatwick/baggage-posters/september_2013_combined.pdf) Some airports will also show the current status of bag delivery (first bag, last bag). Not sure if that information is available in standardized feeds, I don't even think the arrival gate or baggage claim number are widely available via third-party tools, are they? [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [May 4 at 8:05](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173443/where-can-i-see-how-long-it-took-for-checked-in-luggage-to-be-made-available-at#comment433348_173443)
> - You are asking for the impossible. Nobody has all that data in one convenient place for you to query. [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill) [May 4 at 3:40](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173443/where-can-i-see-how-long-it-took-for-checked-in-luggage-to-be-made-available-at#comment433341_173443)